# background music only in first activity

Tags: android, eclipse

I only want to have background music in my first activity (MainActivity). When I Change to the next activity after clicking on a button, I want the music to stop.  Is the the following code is enough, or do I have to implement the button, too?

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();
```

Comment: You can either stop the music in your onClick or in onPause/onStop and then restart it in onResume/onCreate so it will start when your activity becomes active again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the `onPause()` method  in your first `activity`, and pause/stop the music :)

```
@Override
 public void onPause() {
   if(mp.isPlaying()){  
      mp.pause();
      //mp.stop();
   }
  super.onPause(); 
}
```

and even you can use the `onResume()` method to start again the music.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    mp.start();
    super.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make sure to stop the music when another activity launches.  If you want it to start again if they return to this activity, you'll need to code that, likely by using startActivityForResult and activating it on result.  Do you want it to play even if they hit the home button and hide the activity?  If not, the easiest thing to do it start it in onResume and pause it in onPause.